# sharepoint adding space for field with no content

Tags: 2013, 2010

I have a field in pagelayout.

When I save the page with the field empty, in the view mode, sharepoint adds

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Is it sharepoint default behavior? is there  a way to avoid this?

Comment: Is your page customized? or is the default page from where you do input?

Comment: it is customized

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue the pages in the publishing library. Had to use this workaround:

```
$(function(){
$("#hp-colcl .su-rm-description").each(function (){$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'')); $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\u200B/g,''));});
})
```